# CSS: Strange box appears after :hover

Tags: html, css

I am fiddling with CSS/HTML/PHP and I have a :hover to change the background color, but when I hover my cursor over the navigation panes (.navright is just a class of lists), there are strange gray boxes that appear on the top right.

This doesn't happen all the time, but I've noticed that if I move the cursor slowly over the element, then the box appears. If I move the mouse quickly over the element, then it won't appear. However, once it appears, it stays there and I have been unable to fix this!

This is my code:

```
.navright a {
    display: block;

    text-align: left;

    width: 180px;
    height: 24px;

    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
    color: #141414;

    padding: 3px 0px;
    margin: 2px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navright:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

<<>>

Comment: Have you checked if there are any CSS rules for `:hover` on the parent elements? Or by element type?

Comment: That's the only one for that branch

Comment: I am running this locally on Apache. I wouldn't imagine that being a problem, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening

Comment: Yes, but where you're running the server does not interfere with the styles that are being rendered. Can you post part of that HTML/CSS code to JSfiddle? It would be easier to understand the issue that way.

Comment: Can't detect the same issue on that jsfiddle. Do you see the same result?

Comment: Sorry, just saw the same issue on the last button! Let me check what is causing this

Comment: Haha no worries, you really do have to move the mouse very slowly over it for it to appear for some reason... my mind is simply blown away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue relies on the `overflow: scroll;` property you are assigning to `*` (all the elements on the page). For some reason this is rendering that strange shape outside of the `<a>` elements. Not really sure why, but the solution is as follows:

https://jsfiddle.net/hyk4jtwe/5/

1. Remove the `overflow: scroll;` from the `*` selector.
2. To ensure that the menu still retains its initial size, add a `clear` fix as a pseudo selector on the `.navbarTop` element, like so:

(you can apply `clear` fixes in several different ways, but this is the less intrusive way)

```
.navbarTop:after{
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```

After this is done, you'll need to add some minor sizing adjustments to fix the hight of links and that should fix your problem.

---

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 /* Reset the defaults */
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#webpage {
 background-color: #efefef;
}

#navmenu {
 height: 55px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbarTop:after{
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}

.navbarTop {
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color: royalblue;

 min-width: 40em;
}

.navtop {
 min-width: 100px;
 min-height: 40px;
 height: 100%;
 margin-top: 5px 0px;
 float: left;
 padding: 5px 0px;
}

#buddyTitle, .navtop a {
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;

 padding: 10px 40px;

 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}

#buddyTitle {
 float: left;
 min-width: 150px;
 min-height: 40px;

 font-weight: 580;
 font-size: 35px;
 font-family: Garamond;
 letter-spacing: 0.25rem;
}

.navtop a {
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
 letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
}

.navtop:hover {
 background-color: #314fa7;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .7s;
    -moz-transition: background-color .7s;
    -o-transition: background-color .7s;
    transition: background-color .7s;
}
```

```html
 <body id = "webpage">
  <!-- Navigation pane on the top with the header -->
  <div id = "navmenu">
   <ul class = "navbarTop">
    <li id = "buddyTitle">Title</li>
    <li class = "navtop"><a href = "example.com">Test1</a></li>
    <li class = "navtop"><a href = "example.com">Test2</a></li>
        <li class = "navtop"><a href = "example.com">Test3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Perfectly fixed the problem! Thank you. I would just love to know why the overflow would cause that kind of problem

Comment: Sometimes issues like this are minor rendering bugs. We never know. But I strongly suggest following the HTML and CSS specs as much as possible, to prevent unknown problems like this. The `*` selector should be used very carefully. But I'm glad this solved your issue!

Comment: Thank you very much (I'm still learning, as you could probably tell)!

Answer (score 0):

remove `overflow: scroll` from the `*` selector